# Create an html page whose select elements options are the same

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am building a simple web page to register some associations between documents and post codes.

On the left side there is a text with the document's information, and on the right side there is a select element which contains all the values the user will select.

Currently what I am doing is running a query in the documents table , creating an html table whose first `<td>` is the text needed and the second `<td>` contains a select.

That select is populated with data from another query from the post_codes table.

My problem is that even though this runs fine it creates a huge web page. The post_codes table contains over one thousand rows and the documents table will contain typically over four hundred rows.

Is there a way to put all the options for the (over 400) select elements somewhere (like a link) and then make the select elements show those options?

Here is what is currently created

```
<td name="document_123342">Code:123342 Name:mister mister</td>
<td name="post_code_123342">
    <Select>
        <Option value="1234">1234</Option>
        <Option value="1235">1235</Option>
        <Option value="1236">1236</Option>
        ....
    </Select>
</td>
```

Ideally what I would want is something like this: (I have no idea if it is possible just mentioning it)

```
(some sort of source statement here with a name like post_code_values)
        <Option value="1234">1234</Option>
        <Option value="1235">1235</Option>
        <Option value="1236">1236</Option>


<td name="document_123342">Code:123342 Name:mister mister</td>
<td name="post_code_123342">
    <Select>
        (somehow insert everything with the name post_code_values)
    </Select>
</td>
```

Comment: You could load the data by running an ajax query to retrieve data from the server whenever an option has been selected from the list. That way you can retrieve the options dynamically without having to have them all on the initial page.

Comment: my problem is not retrieving the data, the problem is populating the option list with the same data a LOT of times. If you mean when the user clicks the select element , to load the data at that time, that will not do either because this will create a lot of unnecessary load times.

Comment: the database currently contains over 300 post codes, it could expand, but it will definitely not become less, so this will take some time

Answer (score 0):

How about in your table, where you currently have the drop-down with the postcodes, you replace it with a 'select postcode' button, which shows a pop-up or lightbox, with the list of postcodes. Then when the user selects a postcode, it is stored in a hidden field in your table for that row. This way, you only need one copy of the `select` list of postcodes.

See what I mean in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezeshech/6/)

Comment: that was my backup plan, I created a page where there is a button instead of a select which when clicked focused on a list that is always shown to the right of the table with all the cities/post_codes, that's what I'll probably go with, I was just wandering if there is a better way to handle this

Comment: Another thing you could do is to have just one select list, but move it around every time a document is selected. However, this might be a bad UI design choice.

Comment: yeah I've thought of that too, that's basically what I'm doing with the fixed list to the right, only difference is that instead of showing and focusing the list I move a select element, I've done it before on some Visual Basic projects, I'm not very fond of the idea, seems a bit hackish

Comment: Or you could have them type in the postcode in a text field, and then validate it against the postcode list